# Display image then replace uploaded image

Tags: javascript, image, display

I want to upload images, (but first) click on Image(input button to upload Images) Display button then replace new Image ON button images.

Function `displayUploadimages` dosen't work but if I change "**Class**" to "**Id**" all codes work.

Here Codes :

```
  <div class="detail_left">
    <div class="Take">
      <div class="image-upload" onclick="displayUploadimages()">
       <label for="file-input">
         <div class="takes backgrounds"></div>
       </label>
      </div>
      <img class="Uploaded" src="#" alt="">
     </div>
  <input id="file-input" class="" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.Uploaded')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(350)
                .height(350);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
function displayUploadimages() {
          document.getElementsByClassName("image-upload").style.display = "none";
          }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the method , `document.getElementsByClassName` , returns an array and not the element itself, changing this to id will work.

If you want to use classname then do this as follows:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByCLassName('image-upload');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
     elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```